# How do I implement fetching of language for localisation from the backend?

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented localisation for a few languages in the app itself. However I want to fetch localisation files for other languages through the backend. How do I proceed doing this?

Also is it a good practice for Apple standards to read localisation file from the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Since the bundle can't be changed and  `NSLocalizedString` reads from it , then you need to create your own function that returns a value from  what you receive from server ( possibly a dictionary ) something like this for many languages

```
{
   "en" : {
      "key1" : "value1",
      "key2" : "value2"
    }
   ,
   "fr" : {
      "key1" : "value1",
      "key2" : "value2"
    }
}
```

Comment: the implementation is simple access a value from a dictionary with key like **dic["Hello"]** and that what happens unde the hood of **NSLocalizedString** sure according to the current **AppleLanguages** values in userdefaults

Comment: there is no options in your case ( reading localization from backend ) to select that best practice from , one advantage is localization is dynamic instead of submitting new build for edited localization values